# Long URL diffrent Domain redirect Nginx Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, unix, redirect, url-rewriting

What is the best way in Nginx to redirect two Long domains URLS, I would like to configure a redirect between two domains like this:

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

original link:

https://qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-science

New link

https://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science

we are using alb for http to https

I have tried this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc;
    return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science$request_uri;
}
```

output i got

```
 curl -I qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc  
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Location: https://qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc
```

Still receive some errors

```
nginx: [warn] server name "education/7/abc-scienc
" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf:9

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

do i need to use this way to redirect form my old URL to new ?

```
location = /content/unique-page-name {
  return 301 /new-name/unique-page-name;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ? What is wrong here ?

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working correctly. Nginx is returning `301 Moved Permanently` which is what you want. If you want `curl` to actually follow the redirect, you need to add `-L`, e.g.

```
curl -L qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc
```

Explanation from the `curl` docs:

> -L, --location
> (HTTP/HTTPS) If the server reports that the requested page  has  moved  to  a  different  location
> (indicated  with  a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the
> request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or  -I,  --head,  headers  from  all
> requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the
> initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it won't  be  able  to  intercept  the
> user+password.  See  also  --location-trusted  on  how to change this. You can limit the amount of
> redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.
>
> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will
> do  the  following  request  with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
> code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request  using  the  same  unmodified
> method.

Comment: thanks , but still having some problem : nginx: [warn] server name "education/7/abc-scienc
" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf:9